# wifi bluetooth not turning on htc 516

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

when i switched on phone it is not turning WI-fi or blue tooth on but mobile data is working.need help want to fix it.i done restore hard reset but no use. WI-FI based apps also not working.

Comment: What excatly happens when you try to turn on the WiFi/Bluetooth? Does it turns back off, Or are the options disabled?

Comment: try this, Go to Recovery mode and clear cache(ONLY CACHE AND DALVIK CACHE). Then, reboot and check.